# Doing my first facebook app

Tags: facebook

I've been reading through the getting started and core concepts section of the documentation but I still have some problems. First of all I can't get my app to work in general. I wanted to test my app on MAMP localhost so I am using http://localhost:8888/vote/ and https://localhost:8888/vote/ as my secure canvas URL.

I am using http://localhost:8888/vote/index.html and https://localhost:8888/vote/index.html as my Page Tab URL, but I can't select the App in the settings dropdown list where I can define the base Tab for my Facebook site.

I think that's a problem with the SSL certificate that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Did you entered the application profile page and clicked "Add to my page"?
you can find the application profile page here https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=$applicationID